# Is it possible to reinstall iMovie in case I delete it?

Tags: macos, imovie

I'm considering to delete iMovie since I'm not using it at all and it takes more than 2.5 GB. But before deleting it, is it possible to reinstall it in the future in case I want to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its on the app store:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id408981434?mt=12
You can reinstall it from there.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot reinstall iMovie from the APP store if you delete it.

This means a 2 hour call with APPLE.

Comment: This answer differs from the accepted one, do you have any source? In my perspective, accepted one's link *is* iMovie at App Store, and I am able to reinstall it.